# return chalice Response object from chalicelib/utils.py

Tags: python, return, aws-lambda, serverless-framework, chalice

Using AWS Chalice, and suppose `app.py` looks like this:

```
from chalice import Chalice, Response
from chalicelib.utils import some_class

app = Chalice(app_name='myApp')
app.debug = True

@app.route('/myRoute',
       methods=['POST'],
       content_types=['application/octet-stream'])
def myRoute():
   some_class_instance = some_class()
   some_class_instance.some_def()

   return Response(
      body={'hello': 'world'},
      headers={'Content-Type': 'application/json'})
```

and in `utils.py`:

```
import requests
from chalice import Response

class some_class:
    def some_def():
        return Response(
             body={'key1': 'val1'},
             headers={'Content-Type': 'application/json'})
```

The return statement from `some_class.some_def` is not returned to the client if written as shown. But if I run `some_def` from inside `app.py` it is returned. Why?

How can I return objects to the client from outside of `app.py`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is trivially simple (hint from a colleague). You evaluate the returned value from `some_def` in the caller function (`myRoute`). If it's non-empty you return that one. Using the example from the question, `app.py` looks like so:

```
from chalice import Chalice, Response
from chalicelib.utils import some_class

app = Chalice(app_name='myApp')
app.debug = True

@app.route('/myRoute',
           methods=['POST'],
           content_types=['application/octet-stream'])
def myRoute():
    some_class_instance = some_class()
    r = some_class_instance.some_def()
    if r:
        return r
    else:
        return Response(
               body={'hello': 'world'},
               headers={'Content-Type': 'application/json'})
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to keep application code in `app.py`  this solution is for `multifile` support.

You can create a chalicelib/ directory, and anything in that directory is recursively included in the deployment package

```
├── app.py
├── chalicelib
│   └── __init__.py
|   └── utils.py
└── requirements.txt
```

And then in your app.py import like this

```
from chalicelib.utils import SomeClass

some_class = SomeClass()
some_class.some_def()
```

Comment: Hi Raja, my folder structure is exactly as you show it. This also becomes clear from my imports. Note that I already proposed a solution, which works for me. The client calls a route in lambda, and only return statements from that route go back to the client. So I captured returns from `utils.py` in that route (or def) in `app.py` et voila...

Answer (score 0):

I can't see that you call some_class.some_def in utils.py. You need to call function like you did it in app.py:

```
some_class.some_def()
```

Comment: I'm calling `some_def` in `app.py`, perhaps that isn't clear from my example (but originally forgot to instantiate the class but just corrected it). If I run that same code inside `app.py` it returns the body to the client. But if written as shown is does not. Hope that clarifies it.